# Rails: Enum field taking nil value even though default value set as 0

Tags: ruby-on-rails, enums

I have defined following `enum` fields in my model:

```
class ClientRegistration < ApplicationRecord
  enum status: { pending: 0, registered: 1, activated: 2, suspended: 3 }
  enum cloud_type: { onprem: 0, aws: 1, gcp: 2, azure: 3 }
end
```

The migration file for the same looks like below:

```
class CreateClientRegistrations < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
  def change
    create_table :client_registrations do |t|
      t.string :instance_id
      t.string :private_ip
      t.string :mac_address
      t.integer :cloud_type, default: 0
      t.string :public_ip
      t.string :region
      t.integer :status, default: 0

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

Now the strange thing is, my first column status doesn't get it's default value if I don't specify any. Also it doesn't take the first value if I specify explicitly as `pending`. But it works in case of my second column `cloud_type`, it gets the default as `onprem`, if I don't specify any. Do I need to change the column_name or so?

Comment: If you do `ClientRegistration.new.inspect` from a `rails console`, what does it give you for status/cloud_type? If that looks right it might be something with the form, would you be able to show us what you are doing for those fields?

Comment: In addition to @JonathanBennett comment you could try a different name other than status. This may be a red herring but Have a feeling that status might be a reserved word, but having looked through the list of reserved words it's not there, so maybe not but maybe worth a go

Comment: Status should be fine. Its even used as the example in the docs https://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.2.3/classes/ActiveRecord/Enum.html

Comment: How do you create the `client_registration` object? Through controller or console? If you do it from controller, it might be because user don't select any value, then the view send nil value to to controller.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try to add "null: false" to the migration.

```
  t.integer :cloud_type, null: false, default: 0

  t.integer :status, null: false, default: 0
```

Answer (score 0):

When you add a default value during table creation/migration (e.g. `default: 0`), it only works on creation; by passing that value to the column when a value is not presented.

That doesn't work when you update the column after it's already created. To fix that you may validate the enum in the model, similar to this:

```rb
validates :status, presence: true, inclusion: { in: statuses.keys }
validates :cloud_type, presence: true, inclusion: { in: cloud_types.keys }
```

I hope this helps.